# JAWS screen reader is announcing both the name of the two buttons when navigating on second button

Tags: accessibility, jaws-screen-reader

While navigating the "unsubscribe" button screen reader announcing both elements as view results and unsubscribe

```
           <div  role="cell" >
                        <div >
                            <span >
                                <a  aria-label="Data Science &amp; Machine Learning View Results" >
                                  View Results 
                                </a>
                            </span>
                            <span>
                                <button role="button" 
                                  aria-label="Data Science &amp; Machine Learning Unsubscribe">  
                                  Unsubscribe 
                                </button>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Comment: Nothing looks wrong in your code at first glance. Can you post a demo page ? Can you also precise which browser you are using with which version of Jaws exactly ? Thank you.

Comment: unrelated, but since this is an accessibility question anyway: 1) you do not need a `role="button"` on a `button` element, it's there as an implicit role anyway, 2) the `a` with no `href` won't work as you likely expect (eg you won't be able to interact with it via the keyboard at all), either add an `href` or, if you don't intend for it to be a link, make it a `span` instead.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not quite clear either on what you're asking for.  By "navigate", do you mean you are tabbing to the link and the button (which, as @RobinZigmond pointed out, you can't tab to the link because it doesn't have an `href`) or are you using the up/down arrow keys to walk the DOM or are you using the K key to navigate to the link and the B key to navigate to the button?  There are lots of ways to "navigate" with a screen reader.  Are you specifically saying when you get to the "unsubscribe" button that you're hearing **both** the "unsubscribe" label **and** the "view results" label?

Comment: @slugolicious even though link with href is having same issue .the issue is when the navigation goes to unsubscribe it reads both view results and unsubscribe

Comment: Again, how are you navigating?